# Python_getting a count in a sequence of numbers then deviding it by length

Tags: python

Okay, so basically I have a list (seq) of 19 letters of DNA.

```
"CGGTACAATCGATTTAGAG"
```

I am looking to get the right code to count `'A','T','G','C'.`

I have tried.

```
dna_count = seq.count <i>(i have done this for each letter)</i> 
then i used: dna_fraction = dna_count/len(seq)
print(dna_fraction * 100)
```

this results in an error of, `dna_count` is not defined.

I also need to incorporate `round()` to 2d.p of the percentage outcome. and return this.

Code *(from comment)*:

```py
def percentBases(dnaStrand):
    seq = "CGGTACAATCGATTTAGAG"
    dna_count = seq.count("A") + seq.count("T") + seq.count("G") + seq.count("C")
    dna_fraction = dna_count / len(seq)
    print(dna_fraction * 100)
    rawPerCent = 100/seq.count
    percentC = round(rawPercent, 2)
    return (percentC, percentG, percentA, percentT)
```

Error message *(from comment)*:

```
dna_fraction = dna_count / len(seq)
NameError: name 'dna_count' is not defined
```

Comment: Please show the *actual, complete* code that you *actually tried*, and the *actual, complete* error message (including the stack trace). Copy and paste both, and format them properly for posting by re-selecting the entire pasted block and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: def percentBases(dnaStrand):
seq = “CGGTACAATCGATTTAGAG”
dna_count = seq.count(“A”) + seq.count(“T”) + 
seq.count(“G”) + seq.count(“C”)
dna_fraction = dna_count / len(seq)
print(dna_fraction * 100)
rawPerCent = 100/seq.count
percentC = round(rawPercent, 2)
return (percentC, percentG, percentA, percentT)


error message:

dna_fraction = dna_count / len(seq)
NameError: name 'dna_count' is not defined

Comment: Take a look on [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: This code does not produce the error message you describe. You need to have a more organized process so that you can be sure that you are running the code you think you are running, you know what error messages belong with which attempt at the code, and you can paste them *into your original question* yourself and format them as I described.

Comment: Got it to work, thank you everyone. Would i be correct in saying it is O(n^2) Complexity, as it has addition which would be O(n) and then multiplication making it O(n^2)?

Comment: @goku, complexity will be O(4n), because you're iterating over sequence 4 times to count occurrences of each char. `Counter` has O(n) complexity, so it should be quite more efficient. Btw, if one of answer helped you, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

seq = "CGGTACAATCGATTTAGAG"
for element, count in Counter(seq).items():  # use Counter(seq).most_common() for sorted
    print(f"{element}: {count / len(seq):.2%}")
```

Or you can do it in one line:

```py
print(*(f"{e}: {c / len(seq):.2%}" for e, c in Counter(seq).items()), sep="\n")
# print("\n".join(f"{e}: {c / len(seq):.2%}" for e, c in Counter(seq).items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seq = "CGGTACAATCGATTTAGAG"
# use set to find every unique letter
for dna in set(seq):
    # count total number for each DNA in sequence
    dna_count = dna_count.count(dna)
    # divide by total
    dna_fraction = dna_count/len(seq)
    # round by 2
    dna_fraction = round(dna_fraction, 2)
    # print percentage of dna in sequence
    print(dna, dna_fraction * 100)
```